# Pandas data selection error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading two lists from csv files, then trying to access a specific value in pandas array using a value from the list, however I receive a KeyError, which is strange since if I input the string by hand it works, also if I call the whole column it also works. Can you please advise what is wrong here?

```py
tickerList=list(csv.reader(open(path + "\\tickers.csv","rb"),delimiter=','))
dates=list(csv.reader(open(path + "\\dates.csv","rb"),delimiter=','))

def test_run():

#read data into temp dataframe
dataMatrix = pd.read_csv(path + "\histPrice.csv", index_col = "Date", parse_dates = True, na_values=['nan'])
compositionMatrix = pd.read_csv(path + "\composition.csv", index_col = "Ticker", parse_dates = True, na_values=['nan'])
```

This does not work

```
print compositionMatrix[dates[1]]["MMM US Equity"]
```

This works

```py
print compositionMatrix["2005.07.31"]["MMM US Equity"]
```

This works

```py
print compositionMatrix[dates[1]]
```

Comment: Did you try the `loc` method of your DataFrame ?

Comment: `loc()` gave the same error, I think the mistake was in the way lists of tickers and dates were loaded. They were all read from one column, which resulted in tickerList and date being an array with lots of arrays. I pasted all the data in the first row instead of a column, now lists are arrays with variables and loc() seems to work fine. Still do not understand why such an error was appearing as the strings that were called in both ways were the same.